# openvpn and website on the same server/ip

Tags: openvpn

I have connected to my OpenVPN server, when i do traceroute to any host i see that my request goes to my VPN server and then to host i request. But when i request a host from the same server/IP as my vpn server i see that the traffic goes through my provider. Is it possible to access websites that are on VPN server like other websites, while using VPN. Similar problem [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/641345/access-website-hosted-on-same-server-as-vpn-via-the-vpn). Unfortunately without answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a routing problem.

In order to establish and maintain a connection to your VPN, your VPN client must have a route route to the address you are using on the server for incoming VPN connections.  Assuming standard routing, this means anything destined for the same IP used VPN server will directly cross the Internet.

Options.

- The short basic answer is get and use separate IP address for your VPN server.  Don't use the same IP you use for your VPN for anything else.
- Setup some a DNS server on your VPN host and and deliver records for the hosted sites map to internal IP addresses when you are connected.
- If you are running Linux as your client then you could mess around with policy routing and multiple tables, and send only 1194 traffic through the standard table, and port http/https traffic over the VPN.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, could you please explain option 2, 3 in details. Do you know if i will use server IPv6 address for VPN, will this problem exists?

Comment: +1 it'd be super helpful if you could give some details on those options. I'm stuck in the same situation and can't figure out if they're viable.